# (rails) working with forms and javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Every Ingredient has one Category.

First a user selects a Category then

store all ingredients of that category into a second select field.

```
<%= select("category", "category_id", Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }) %>
```

My approach is to update the second select field with ajax, but once placing the ajax call after the alert statement the whole function is not called anymore.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change', '#category_category_id', function(){
    alert("changed");
    $.ajax({
      url: "categories/category_selection",
      type: "GET",
      data: {'ingredient=' + $('#ingredient_selection option:selected').value() },
    })
  });
});
```

Same with

```
$('#category_category_id').live('change', function(){...})
```

Categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def category_selection
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js {  }
    end
  end
end
```

Category_selection.js.erb

```
$('#category_category_id').after('
  <%= select_tag :category_selection, 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@ingredients, :id, :name), 
        :prompt => "Ingredient" %>
');
```

Comment: So the function works without the ajax call? I would remove the last comma in the ajax call (after the data hash). I would also add a semi-colon after `$('#ingredient_selection option:selected').value()`

Comment: $.ajax({ 
url: "categories/category_selection", 
type: "GET", 
data: {'ingredient=' + $('#ingredient_selection option:selected').value(); }}) 
doesnt work (also with an semicolon at the end)

Comment: Hmmm. What errors are you getting in your browser's console when you run that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{'ingredient=' + $('#ingredient_selection option:selected').value() }
```

Causes a syntax error. The brackets are interpreted as the beginning of an object literal but instead you have an expression which evaluates into a string.

You should pass a string or object as the data parameter.

```
data: 'ingredient=' + $('#ingredient_selection option:selected').value(),
```

or an object:

```
data: { ingredient: $('#ingredient_selection option:selected').value() },
```

I would recommend that you learn to use the [browser console](http://wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/).

[image]

Comment: Now the alert is executed. But the view stays untouched

Comment: You do realize how ajax works? It does not replace the page content.

Comment: If you look in the network tab you can see the request, but if you actually want to do something with the data you needto register a success handler. Google for "jquery ajax tutorial"